# A loop of closed Mass Effect questions

Tags: discussion, closing

I'm kind of having an issue with a question I had closed and not sure what to do about it, so thought I would bring it to attention here.

I originally asked about changes imported from [ME1 to ME2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/to-what-extent-do-your-choices-in-mass-effect-influence-the-story-in-the-sequel).

Recently I wanted to ask about changes [from ME2 DLCs to ME3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52478/will-the-decisions-made-in-mass-effect-dlcs-carry-into-me3), since enough reviews are popping up that the question seems answerable.

Before asking I had searched for similar questions, but they did not seem to apply. My question was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50947/what-side-quests-dlc-and-achievements-should-i-make-sure-to-complete-in-prepar) which refers to ME3 in the title.

However the person who asked the question clarified that he was concerned about changes from ME1 to ME2, so it was closed as a duplicate of my original question.

In this case, should the question which only refers to ME3 title have the title edited to reflect that the question does not actually ask about ME3, which would then allow my question on ME3 to be reopened as it is clearly not a dupe?

Answer (score 6):

> A more official policy for this type of pre-release question has superseded this answer: [How should we handle non-beta pre-release questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/how-should-we-handle-non-beta-pre-release-questions)

This is kind of a murky pool we've been wading around in, so I'm certainly open to various solutions.

LessPop asked "what carries over to ME3 from ME1 and ME2?" which was closed for two reasons - one is that it's *speculation on an upcoming release* (the ME3 part) and the part that could be answered now is a *duplicate of another question.*  We only get to pick one reason, and for the time being his concern was primarily around the games he *can* play, so it got closed as a duplicate.

I'd like to think that he knew there was already a ME1->ME2 carryover question, and the "new" part of his question was "what carries over from both games to ME3?"  I believe that, after the game is launched, we will be back to that question to answer it.

Your question is "what carries over from ME2->ME3" - which is *part* of the question asked by LessPop.  In this case, we've still got the same two problems, just with a different duplicate question.

If you think that we can now answer the question of "what carries over from the earlier ME games to ME3," it's my opinion that we should then re-open LessPop's question.  It's my opinion that if LessPop's question had been open and answerable, yours would still be a duplicate.

Comment: Your interpretation of my question would be correct. I was interested in carryovers from the first to the second that would continue into the third. While the question which mine was closed as a duplicate of provides a set of data from which my answe might be drawn, it is, functionally, a superset of the information that I actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, my questions was specific to DLC's influencing mass effect. Not mass effect 2 but only the DLCs. i.e. lair of the shadowbroker, arrival, not the game itself.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53539/is-liara-the-shadow-broker-in-mass-effect-3-even-if-you-havent-done-the-dlc) and the recent comment on the question this meta question is about both show in my opinion that the question is not a dupe.