# Question deleted after it was edited to be relevant?

Tags: support

I posted a question about a feature in the Skyrim DLC before it was released and it was quickly closed, which I understood. However after the release of the DLC I edited the question to make it relevant so I could receive  and it was possible for it to be answered since the content it was based on had been released. However shortly after I submitted my request for the question to be reopened i was deleted which I did not understand. I was told it was closed because The DLC had no been released so why the sudden deletion when it became relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was one of the three people who voted to delete it. Sorry about that!

While agent86 is correct in [explaining why it was closed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5058/3389), in any normal circumstance, your question would've likely been reopened, having survived through the pre-release period.

To that end, [we briefly discussed re-opening your question in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5130675#5130675), but I placed the third vote to delete (and thus deleted your question) because it was one of a number of questions that asked the same thing: what changes did Dawnguard bring to curing lycanthropy?

And we also have another question that's been around since the beginning:

> [How can I cure lycanthropy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/has-anyone-actually-cured-lycanthropy)

Because questions can attract new answers and existing answers can be edited, it's not necessary to re-ask a question when new information that can extend or invalidate existing answers comes to light.

So, since we had a number of duplicate questions already, I:

- added a bounty to the original question asking for information from the Dawnguard DLC
- voted to delete your question, being already closed and one vote away from deletion anyway

I *should've* left a comment pointing you to the canonical question, and I'm sorry I didn't.

Comment: I don't believe it's currently the policy to reopen a question that was asked pre-release if it manages to avoid deletion up until release, do you have a link or source for that?  If we haven't discussed it, discussing it would probably be best.

Comment: @agent86 The only reason pre-release questions are closed is because they are unanswerable: after release, they are answerable. If the question is now relevant and answerable and would survive if it had been re-asked, why *wouldn't* you re-open it?

Comment: @agent86 To be clear, I don't intend to say that you or other moderators should personally re-open questions after release. I'm merely saying had this question been the only one that had asked about curing lycanthropy, the community would've likely re-opened it despite the whole "but it's not fair" argument made in the question you linked in your answer.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation. It was just a major factor in my purchase of dawnguard. If an addition has been made to the original lycanthropy question then thats fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the question (10k only):

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73400/lycanthropy-cure-in-dawnguard-dlc

In the run-up to the Mass Effect 3 launch, the issue of what we do with questions asked pre-release was brought up, and the community consensus was that they would be closed and deleted.  You can see the rationale behind this decision here on meta:

[How should we handle non-beta pre-release questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/how-should-we-handle-non-beta-pre-release-questions/)

Comment: I can't speak for Grace Note's intentions in that post, but the fact that the question was deleted after the DLC was released is a little troubling to me.  There was no clear stance on when a question should be deleted (just that it be marked for pending deletion), but IMHO it should have been deleted before the DLC was released instead of the apparent knee jerk reaction after.

Comment: @MBraedley Voters are slow sometimes. It happens. /shrug.