# Am I allowed to ask about beta testing games?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask about tips on becoming a beta tester. Like which is more important, whether it's testing for Windows, or for Mac, and which one gives me a better chance to be chosen as a tester.

Are these allowed?

Comment: Your title says one thing and your content sayd anoth... Erm, *something*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There appears to be multiple questions here, depending on whether you're paying attention to the topic or the question body.

Yes - [you are allowed to ask about games which are publicly available](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5539/52800), either as alpha versions through Kickstarter or open beta or whatever.

However, a question about methodologies that would provide you the best opportunity to be chosen as a beta tester would be off topic here as they're not a practical problem that you're experiencing while playing games.

Additionally, this would be a very broad field as each company looking for beta testers would have different criteria that they would be looking for in their testers, making it impractical within our Q&A format.