# Are questions about unreleased consoles on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

The Xbox one and PS4 will shortly be released. I know that questions about unreleased **games** are off topic, however there is a fair amount of information the we have access to specifically about these two consoles.

Are questions about unreleased consoles on topic?

Comment: As someone that has worked on unreleased hardware & software right up until the release of said hard/software, I can tell you that nothing is set in stone until you are physically holding one on the way home from the store.(and even then you can have product recalled for fault reasons)

Comment: Related: [This question about an unreleased console has an answer, should it be opened and answered?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7903/this-question-about-an-unreleased-console-has-an-answer-should-it-be-opened-and)

Comment: I've generified this question so that it applies to future unreleased consoles as well

Answer (score 19):

No.

This follows the same rule as [When is a game publicly available?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5539/52800). Until the products are publicly available for use, any so called "publicly available information" is subject to change (see: Xbox One).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, no.

Even though there's a lot of information 'out there', there's just as much speculation and until the answers can be given by a typical gamer based off what they've experienced rather than what Sony/Microsoft tell them, there's no way we can realistically answer questions.