# Is there actually a gap time between game release and question asking?

Tags: discussion, support

User MattR made a [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194323/how-do-i-get-the-impossible-it-can-t-be-is-it-achievement#comment263253_194323) on a [question on Payday 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/194323/18916):

> A reasonable time would have been better, rather than directly after
>   the came out. Overkill can, and have, been cryptic in how certain
>   achievements have been reached. You didn't even give enough time to
>   actually try between release and post.

I have been on this site for about two years so far and so far I have not heard yet of a "gap time" between post-release and question asking.    As far as I know, the rules have been: Don't ask questions about unreleased games and content.

I asked that question shortly after the update came out, asking it after I had actually played the heist.

Unfortunately I am unsure as of now what to do. Did I err here? Is there really this fabled "gap time" that MattR speaks of?

Comment: I believe our stance is *If a general user (not press or inside source) can play the content, then questions about it are acceptable.*  Also, [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8656/42984) is related to your question.

Comment: You are allowed to ask such questions. People are allowed to downvote such questions.

Comment: @Sterno My question wasn't regarding downvotes, my question was regarding if there was such a gap time as the user claimed there was.

Comment: The user never claimed there was a "gap time" rule or any such thing. His comments read like explanations of a downvote. I'm not sure where in anything he said (and note, no close votes were cast, nor did he specifically advocate closing) led you to believe there was some sort of community rule about it.

Comment: @Sterno what part of "A reasonable time would have been better, rather than directly after the came out. " did you not understand. Especially "You didn't even give enough time to actually try between release and post."

Comment: I fail to see where he invokes it as some sort of community rule, nor do I see any close votes. It reads a lot more as "here is what I don't like about your question". But you are right, your question isn't about downvotes. It's about whether or not a question which received no close votes or even recommendations for close votes is okay.

Comment: @Sterno I'm asking about a comment someone made; why are you trying to read out of that context?

Comment: We're just both seeing his comment differently. I see it a downvote explanation. You apparently saw it as him referencing some obscure site rule. My initial comment pertains directly to how I believe his comment was intended. I've wondered why you were arguing with me and am guessing you think I'm insinuating that your post was really just a way to whine about the downvote. I can see how it would come off that way and it was not my intention. But I would say a random comment by a 360 rep user, and no close votes with it, probably doesn't need a meta topic.

Comment: @Sterno That was what I initially thought you were going at, thinking I was whining about a downvote. But I just wanted to double check, and honestly, when I posted this question I had not even checked the rep of the user

Comment: I think the only limiting factor on this is how long it will take for someone to have the answer. If you have a question about a bug or glitch for example on the day of release, it might take some time for people to respond. Whereas on the other had (for example) "Where do I find (x) in game (y)" Will most likely get a quicker response.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Nope**. You are allowed to ask as long as it's [publicly available](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available).

As you can see, it took people 4 hours to answer. To say that you need to wait some arbitrary amount of time is, frankly, absurd. Because you probably would have gotten the exact same comments 4 hours later, when people have done it and did have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Gap Time" or anything similar in effect. It appears as if that comment was made by a relatively inactive user who may be less familiar with how our system works. His comment appears to be more at home on something like a forum or message board.

At Arqade, and Stack Exchange in general; there is nothing wrong with a question that nobody has yet discovered the answer to. If you don't get a response, as long as the question is good (upvoted) it will remain in the system, and even be automatically bumped on occasion until an answer is given.

Comment: However... asking a question about an update immediately after said update smacks of Didn't Do The Research.  DDTR questions are routinely closed on other SE sites, such as StackOverflow.

Comment: What kind of research can you do for something that is newly released @Powerlord?

Comment: @memescientist Well, for one... playing the game.

Comment: @Powerlord Which I did.  I had already finished the heist on Deathwish when I had asked that question, and was looking to get the rest of the achievements in that pack

Comment: I think as far as Arqade is considered its more frowned upon then enforced as a rule.  A rule of such would more turn away people asking them.