# Are overseas Games allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

My problem stems from a beta im in, however, that beta is currently on going in South Korea.  So if I were to post a question about said game, would it be closed?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available)

Comment: Of course you might have more trouble getting answers. :)

Comment: Overseas from where?  The internet?

Comment: There's no seas on the internet! Everything is welcome, as long as you didn't sign a NDA for that beta.

Answer (score 20):

You can ask questions about games available in any market, so long as it is a *public* market.

Game available only in SK, but it's a public beta? Great! Game available only in SK, and it's a *private* beta? Not ok, but nothing to do with it only being available in South Korea, rather it's because [we don't like questions about prerelease content](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available).

Comment: Didn't we have questions about both Hearthstone and Heroes of the Storm while they were in Closed Beta? Is that because the size of the player pool was actually fairly large, or something else?

Comment: @scon Probably because nobody made a meta about it.

Answer (score 10):

Post away!

(Keeping in mind the usual caveats about prerelease content - we're not here to enforce anyone's NDA, but the existence of one is a good sign it's probably not a game we want questions about yet - and that Arqade is an english language site.)

Comment: Translation isnt an issue, in general my concern was because its not ported to the US as of yet.